efficient way to return single element by priority order in array of objects javascript
I have following array with three elements:
const tasks = [{
  type: 'critical',
  value: 'production issue',
}, {
  type: 'high',
  value: 'server down'
}, {
  type: 'medium',
  value: 'backup not taken'
}];

Now I declare an empty array which should return an element based on the priority
let priorityTask = []; 


Now, the priority task should return { type: 'critical', value: 'production issue' } since critical type would have highest priority.
If critical type is not available in the array of tasks then it should return { type: 'high', value: 'server down' } as high type would have second priority and like wise.
I have written the following code to get the output which looks just fine But, if we have a large set of array of tasks ? how can we refactor the code to make it better.
Priority Order: Critical - High - Medium
const criticalIndex = tasks.findIndex((task) => task.type === 'critical');
const highIndex = tasks.findIndex((task) => task.type === 'high');
const mediumIndex = tasks.findIndex((task) => task.type === 'medium');

tasks.forEach((task) => {
  if (criticalIndex >= 0) {
    task.type === 'critical' ? priorityTask = task : [];
  } else {
    if (highIndex >= 0) {
      task.type === 'high' ? priorityTask = task : [];
    } else {
      if (mediumIndex >= 0) {
        task.type === 'medium' ? priorityTask = task : [];
      }
    }
  }
});


console.log('priorityTask: ', priorityTask);

{
  type: 'critical',
  value: 'production issue'
}


const priority = ['critical', 'high', 'medium'];
let priorityTask = priority.map(p => tasks.find(task => task.type === p)).find(task => task !== undefined);

console.log('priorityTask:', priorityTask);

Using the priority array we define a sort of hierarchy and find will return the first occurence, so your desired output.

we could simply replace find(task => task !== undefined) with [0]
since the first element returned after the map would always be the one which matches the first element in the priority array

let priorityTask = priority.map(p => tasks.find(task => task.type === p))[0]

You can simplify and generalize the code by using a priority array that defines the order of priority for task types. Here's how you can refactor the code:
const tasks = [
  { type: 'critical', value: 'production issue' },
  { type: 'high', value: 'server down' },
  { type: 'medium', value: 'backup not taken' },
];

const priority = ['critical', 'high', 'medium'];

let priorityTask = tasks.find(task => priority.includes(task.type));

console.log('priorityTask:', priorityTask);

In this refactored code, the priority array defines the order of priority for task types. The find method is used to find the first task in the tasks array whose type is included in the priority array. This approach makes the code more scalable and easier to maintain, especially when you have a larger set of task types.

Thanks for the quick response, But, this won't give the output needed. like if we have the following array of tasks
const tasks = [
{ type: 'high', value: 'server down' },
{ type: 'critical', value: 'production issue' },
{ type: 'medium', value: 'backup not taken' },
];
it would return { type: 'high', value: 'server down' } but the output should be { type: 'critical', value: 'production issue' } Priority wise it should be Critical - High - Medium

Their are multiple approaches to your solution and i cant figure your exact requirement so i have afew approaches that i can share
As you wanted a solution for large set so i have changed the task array for now
const tasks = [
  { type: 'medium', value: 'backup not taken - 2' },
  { type: 'critical', value: 'production issue - 1' },
  { type: 'medium', value: 'backup not taken - 1' },
  { type: 'high', value: 'server down - 2' },
  { type: 'high', value: 'server down - 1' },
  { type: 'critical', value: 'production issue - 2' },
];

Method - 1 : If you just want all the critical task or high or medium task
const getTasks = (type) => {
  return tasks.filter(task => task.type === type);
}

console.log(getTasks('critical'));
//[
//  { type: 'critical', value: 'production issue - 1' },
//  { type: 'critical', value: 'production issue - 2' }
//]

console.log(getTasks('high'));
//[
//  { type: 'high', value: 'server down - 2' },
//  { type: 'high', value: 'server down - 1' }
//]

Method - 2 : get the highest ranking task and delete that task from the array
const priorityOrder = ['critical', 'high', 'medium'];
const getHighestPriorityTask = () => {
    if (tasks.length === 0) {
        return undefined;
    }
    let task;
    for (let i = 0; i < priorityOrder.length; i++) {
        task = tasks.find(task => task.type === priorityOrder[i]);
        if (task) {
            tasks.splice(tasks.indexOf(task), 1);
            return task;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

console.log(getHighestPriorityTask());//{ type: 'critical', value: 'production issue - 1' }
console.log(getHighestPriorityTask());//{ type: 'critical', value: 'production issue - 2' }
console.log(getHighestPriorityTask());//{ type: 'high', value: 'server down - 2' }
console.log(getHighestPriorityTask());//{ type: 'high', value: 'server down - 1' }
console.log(getHighestPriorityTask());//{ type: 'medium', value: 'backup not taken - 2' }
console.log(getHighestPriorityTask());//{ type: 'medium', value: 'backup not taken - 1' }
console.log(getHighestPriorityTask());//undefined

Method - 3 : You can even sort it the sequence of critical > high > medium
const sortedTasks = tasks.sort((a, b) => {
    const priorityOrder = ['critical', 'high', 'medium'];
    const priorityA = priorityOrder.indexOf(a.type);
    const priorityB = priorityOrder.indexOf(b.type);
    return priorityA - priorityB;
});

console.log(sortedTasks);

Hope it helps !!
